# TCP packets with Protobuf messages not dissected

Tags: wireshark, decoding

I'm trying to use Wireshark to dissect Protobuf messages sent over TCP using gRPC. When I view the data portion of a messages, I see raw bytes instead of a dissected view.

I've added the path to the directory containing the Protobuf file in Preferences->Protocols->Protobuf->Protobuf search paths. I've checked "Load .proto files on startup."

In Analyze->Available protocols, Protobuf is selected.

I added the plugin that @harrymc mentioned, and I see this error when I start Wireshark:

```
Lua: Error during loading:
...shark/plugins/4-2/protobuf_dissector-master/protobuf.lua:43: attempt to call field 'prepend_path' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    ...shark/plugins/4-2/protobuf_dissector-master/protobuf.lua:43: in main chunk
```

When I go to Analyze->Decode as.. and add my port number, I don't see a way to choose Protobuf in Current column.

I'm using Wireshark on macOS.

Comment: See Github [protobuf_dissector](https://github.com/128technology/protobuf_dissector) described : "A Wireshark Lua plugin to decode/dissect Google Protobuf messages".